# How to use regular expression in cmake?

Tags: cmake

I want to use the stem of source filename as the executable filename, so I would like to use string(REGEX MATCH) to extract it.
My regular expression has been passed by the online tester.
[image: online test]

In cmakelists.txt, I try to escape "\" then I use "\\" instead of it.

```
file(GLOB_RECURSE testList "*.cpp" )

foreach(testFile ${testList})
    # get the source file name stem as the test execuatale name
    # if the AffineTest.cpp, the test executale is AffineTest
    # Conv2DTest.cpp -> Conv2DTest
    cmake_print_variables(testFile)
    set(TestExecutable "before")
    string(REGEX MATCH \\w+(?=\\.) ${TestExecutable} ${testFile} ) 
    # string(REGEX MATCH AffineTest TestExecutable ${testFile} ) 
    cmake_print_variables(TestExecutable)
    packageAdd2Test(${TestExecutable} ${testFile})
endforeach()
```

However, the matching seems failed.
Does cmake has some features such as literal raw string?

```
-- testFile="/home/robin/DataDisk/RLDNN/dnn/Test/AffineTest.cpp"
-- TestExecutable="before"
```

Comment: Doc regarding literal raw string: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-language.7.html#command-arguments

Comment: CMake regular expressions are described in [string(REGEX)](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/string.html#search-and-replace-with-regular-expressions) command flows. As you could see, these expressions are very simple and support neither ``\w`` nor `?=` constructions.

Comment: I wonder if you are looking for this https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/get_filename_component.html